# Checkbox in DataGridView doesnt Check

Tags: c#, windows, forms, desktop, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I create a DataGridView as follows

```
 private void IniciarGV()
    {
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {

            var ListaPantallas = (from a in db.PANTALLAS
                                  select a).ToList();


            if (ListaPantallas != null)
            {

                gvPermisos.DataSource = ListaPantallas;
                gvPermisos.Columns["idPantalla"].Visible = false;
                gvPermisos.Columns["nombrepantalla"].HeaderText = "Nombre";
                //gvPermisos.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn());
                DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                checkBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Seleccione";
                checkBoxColumn.Width = 50;
                checkBoxColumn.Name = "checkBoxColumn";
                gvPermisos.Columns.Insert(0, checkBoxColumn);
                //gvPermisos.EndEdit();

            }

            db.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

After that a i retrieve the privileges with the same method linq

```
var TraerPermisos = (from a in db.PERMISOS
                                 where a.IDUSUARIO == UsuarioEditar.idUsuario
                                 select a).ToList();
```

After i go through the gridview to match the privileges with the ids that i wanted to check so the user can edit them, but for some reason they always appear unmarked

so far this is what i encounter in every forum or google, but it doesnt seem to work

```
 foreach (PERMISOS item in TraerPermisos)
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gvPermisos.Rows)
                {
                    var ValorPermisoEnGV = Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value);
                    var ValorPantalla = decimal.Parse(row.Cells["idPantalla"].Value.ToString());
                    if (ValorPantalla == item.IDPANTALLA)
                    {
                        row.Cells["checkBoxColumn"].Value = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

this what my form looks like
[image]

I load the privileges on start

```
 public ManejarUsuario()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        IniciarComboBox();
        IniciarGV();
        if (UsuarioEditar.idUsuario != 0)
        {
            CargarDatos();
            btnCrearUsuario.Text = "Editar";
            CargarPrivilegios();
        }
    }
```

Sorry about the long post, i've tried so many options but none seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Life would be a lot easier if you just put a Boolean in the data driving the grid.  First, let's make a holder class for your info

```
class Perms{
  public int IdPantalla { get; set; }
  public string NombrePantalla { get; set; }
  public bool HasPermission { get; set; }
}
```

Then let's have the query produce a list of these instead:

```
//get all the IDPANTALLA this user has and put in a hash set
var TraerPermisos = (from a in db.PERMISOS
    where a.IDUSUARIO == UsuarioEditar.idUsuario
    select a.IDPANTALLA).ToHashSet();

//make a list of objects that includes a bool of whether the user has that permission 
//note you should have this be a class level variable for ease of use later/elsewhere 
ListaPantallas = (from a in db.PANTALLAS
    select new Perms { 
      IdPantalla a.IdPantalla, 
      HasPermission = TraerPermisos.Contains(a.idPantalla) , 
      NombrePantalla = a.nombrepantalla 
    }).ToList();
```

Then set up the grid:

```
gvPermisos.DataSource = ListaPantallas;
gvPermisos.Columns["IdPantalla"].Visible = false;
gvPermisos.Columns[ "NombrePantalla"].HeaderText = "Nombre";
gvPermisos.Columns[ "HadPermission"].HeaderText = "Seleccione";
```

The grid will find the bool property in the list and wire it up for you as a check column. It doesn't need you to make a column for it. Anything you tick is then stored in the underlying list as a true/false and you can eg `foreach(var x in ListaPantallas) if(x.HasPermission...`

When manipulating data in a DGV that is bound to a data source, manipulate the source. Also consider to make Perms implements INotifyPropertyChanged (and consider switching to using a binding list)

Comment: That solve the problem,now it retreat all the info and displayed accordly, but another problem came up, now i can't manually check or uncheck the checkboxes

Comment: Edit: After Inspection the readonly attribute is set to true, but when i set it to false, it throws and exeption wich translate to something like this :
A DataGridView column bound to a read-only file must have ReadOnly set to True

Comment: Yes, sorry I overlooked the part where you were looking to have the user edit the data. An anonymous type is read only. I've adjusted the advice in the newer to create a mutable class you can use instead

Comment: Everything works just fine, thank you so much